# Is it possible to have inches as the default imperial unit?

Tags: units

I work with imperial units quite a bit in Blender. For me it would be more intuitive if the units would default to inches, rather than feet. For example, if I were to use fractional inches in the advanced numerical input mode, I'd have to use the inch marker after each element. It would be nice if 12' 2 3/4" would produce 12 feet 2 and three-quarter inches instead of 14 feet and 3/4 inches...

Comment: You can set it to inches and save your start-up file: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/startup_file.html -> *File > Defaults > Save Start-up File* Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @brockmann. I can change the units to imperial - that's not my problem. What I cannot do is change the default unit of the advanced numeric input mode to _inches_ instead of _feet_.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Searching for it... @Qwerty